# How to change the color of a SVG icon when imbedded in a website builder

Tags: javascript, html, css, scripting

Total newb here but I have this simple question. 
I am building a new site for a client and want to be able to link to a Wistia Popover video directly from a button on the hero section of the website. 
I am sharing the website here. 
http://photography-5-1571342377793.showit.site/

```js
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/xsde7mhige.jsonp" async=""></script><script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async=""></script><span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_xsde7mhige popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline;position:relative"><a href="#"><div class="se-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M265 96c65.3 0 118.7 1.1 168.1 3.3h1.4c23.1 0 42 22 42 49.1v1.1l.1 1.1c2.3 34 3.4 69.3 3.4 104.9.1 35.6-1.1 70.9-3.4 104.9l-.1 1.1v1.1c0 13.8-4.7 26.6-13.4 36.1-7.8 8.6-18 13.4-28.6 13.4h-1.6c-52.9 2.5-108.8 3.8-166.4 3.8h-10.6.1-10.9c-57.8 0-113.7-1.3-166.2-3.7h-1.6c-10.6 0-20.7-4.8-28.5-13.4-8.6-9.5-13.4-22.3-13.4-36.1v-1.1l-.1-1.1c-2.4-34.1-3.5-69.4-3.3-104.7v-.2c-.1-35.3 1-70.5 3.3-104.6l.1-1.1v-1.1c0-27.2 18.8-49.3 41.9-49.3h1.4c49.5-2.3 102.9-3.3 168.2-3.3H265m0-32.2h-18c-57.6 0-114.2.8-169.6 3.3-40.8 0-73.9 36.3-73.9 81.3C1 184.4-.1 220 0 255.7c-.1 35.7.9 71.3 3.4 107 0 45 33.1 81.6 73.9 81.6 54.8 2.6 110.7 3.8 167.8 3.8h21.6c57.1 0 113-1.2 167.9-3.8 40.9 0 74-36.6 74-81.6 2.4-35.7 3.5-71.4 3.4-107.1.1-35.7-1-71.3-3.4-107.1 0-45-33.1-81.1-74-81.1C379.2 64.8 322.7 64 265 64z"></path><path d="M207 353.8V157.4l145 98.2-145 98.2z"></path></svg></div></a></span>
```

As you can see for the first two hero images we just have the icons link to a instagram video. 
On the 3rd hero image you'll see that I have the same SVG icon and it goes to a wistia popover video. 
I just need to figure out what I need to do in order to make the icon white to match the other play icons in the hero section. Im sharing the code that I have here imbedded on the site... As well as a screenshot from my site builder....[screenshot from site builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNTzi.jpg)

Thank's for your help!

-Nathan
509.250.2187

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!

To fix your problem, just add `filter: invert(100%);` instead of `color: white;` on your svg styling. This should fix your problem :)

EDIT:
Based on what I now know, here is what you should do to fix the issue:

instead of just using this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" version="1.1">
   <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

You should go for something like this (add the `style` tag with its contents)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" version="1.1" id="hero-movie-icon">
   <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" fill="green"/>
</svg>

<style>
svg#hero-movie-icon {
filter: invert(100%);
}
</style>
```

Also, notice that I added an `id` attribute to the `svg` tag, so that I can reference the svg more precisely from the css (which is inside of the `style` tag)

Comment: Hey Frikk! Thank you for your help! I think I am making progress here but not quite all the way. I am running the svg section of the code here at https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html Using the following code....Where and how exactly do I add the styling to this? Thanks!

Comment: @NathanReimche-Vu, sorry for the late response, but I updated the answer, maybe you'll find it useful ;)